# Android service_manager.c create file

Tags: android, file, ipc

I would like that the service_manager will create file,
I tried with the open command but I get permission denied,
How can I create a file ?

Is there a way from the system_manager.c to know from the process PID the application name ?

Thanks

Comment: There is no `system_manager.c` in AOSP.  Do you mean `service_manager.c`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean `service_manager.c`:

1) `servicemanager` runs as uid 1000 (`system`) and thus a call to `open()` is bound by the normal filesystem permissions (i.e., what you see in an `ls -l`).  In other words, you can only create a file where uid 1000 has the proper filesystem permissions.

2) `svcmgr_handler()` in `service_manager.c` gets a `binder_txn` structure, `txn`, which looks like this (from `binder.h`):

```
struct binder_txn
{
    void *target;
    void *cookie;
    uint32_t code;
    uint32_t flags;

    uint32_t sender_pid;
    uint32_t sender_euid;

    uint32_t data_size;
    uint32_t offs_size;
    void *data;
    void *offs;
};
```

As you can see, `txn` contains the sender's pid (`txn->sender_pid`).

Now, if you're looking for the application name, this is tied to the uid in Android. Fortunately, the uid is also available in this structure (`txn->sender_euid`).